# Has the "First Post" Review section broken?

Tags: discussion

I have seen the "First Post" review section grown from  the normal 1-3 posts to a whopping 430+ and the reviews are like two days old?

Is this a bug or do they do a massive release of "Re-Reviews" occasionally?

Sorry I tagged it as [discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/discussion) as I saw nothing else that fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nah, this isn't a regular thing.  There was a bug in the system earlier that prevented questions from being added to the queue and it's just been fixed; so all the old questions got put in the queue. See [First Posts review queue is not showing first questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173886/first-posts-review-queue-is-not-showing-first-questions) for more information.

Here is a developer's response to [a comment of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173886/first-posts-review-queue-is-not-showing-first-questions/173892#comment518587_173892):

> @Seth - we were excluding locked posts via a `p.ParentId In (...)`, when `ParentId` is `null` on questions, so it needed a simple `IsNull(p.ParentId, 0)` In `(...)` instead is all.  [– Nick Craver♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173886/first-posts-review-queue-is-not-showing-first-questions)